# Dynamic multiple Autofilter Criteria for Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

We have a tracking list with product IDs in Excel and we frequently have to compare entries for several products using this tracking list. We use the `.AutoFilter`, search for the ID then click on "add to current selection". We repeat that N times. I want to automate this using VBA.

I have constructed an Input collector and as far as I can understand I need to collect the data in an Array.

Here a screenshot of a test worksheet.

[image]

And here a test code that is gets an array and plugs it into `.AutoFilter` with 'xlFilterValues' this does yield not the desired outcome but rather and empty list.

```
Sub Multifilter()

Dim FilteredRNG As Range
Dim TestAR(4) As Long
TestAR(0) = 100034
TestAR(1) = 165738
TestAR(2) = 165510
TestAR(3) = 165512
TestAR(4) = 165567

Set FilteredRNG = Sheet2.Range("B1:B29") ' Get my test range

FilteredRNG.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=TestAR, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Result is here: [image]

If I switch the Operator to `xlOr` the Result changes to:

[image]

My Array looks good during debugging: [image]

So how do I get N IDs selected from the ID list using an array?

Comment: You need to use `Operator:=xlFilterValues` to filter by an array of values. • Also you should remove the parenthesis from `GetArray (varArray)` and `GetFilteredRNG (FilteredRNG)` as they do something different than you think they do. Use `GetArray varArray` or put a `Call` statement infront `Call GetArray(varArray)`. As you have them now they will convert the default `ByRef` parameter into a `ByVal` submission. You can see that because there is a space between the function name `GetArray` and the parenthesis. If that's the case it is a conversion to `ByVal` and the parenthesis needs removed.

Comment: Operator:= xlFiltervalues doesn't work either. FYI: the GerArray and GetFilterRNG are dummy subs that I use to make this code StackOverFlow readable. In my code I have it all spaghettied, but thanks for the info I didn't know that.

Comment: Well then please show a [mcve] of your issue. Because with an proper array and `Operator:=xlFilterValues` it works. Give some example data for your array and some example data you try to filter.

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll update the post with some test data and then it should be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The array needs to be a string in order for it to work.

```
Dim TestAR(4) As String
```

Solves the issue.